# Boot into windows installed virtually from linux

Tags: virtualbox

My question is regarding the possibility of an particular thing. I have Debian installed on my system and have win 8 as an virtual os using virtual box

Is it possible to bypass linux completely or partially and boot directly into the Win 8 virtual OS? maybe creating an entry into grub or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that we can not do that, because the virtual box itself is installed on the Debian so we need the Debian to start the virtual box and then the virtual OS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The best you can get to is converting the Virtualbox .vdi to a partition, but even then it isn't likely to boot. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/114452/127430).

Comment: I understand that converting into partition would not work. But a part of my question was to boot linux partially and only things that are required for Virtual box to run. and load directly into the VDI image.

Comment: You asked about bypassing Linux completely. You could boot a minimal system like ArchLinux or Gentoo or similar, with only the bare minimum you need and VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for doing the same thing I found couple good guides on the web

https://www.maketecheasier.com/log-into-a-virtualbox-session-in-ubuntu/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/404665/how-to-start-virtual-box-machines-automatically-when-booting